# How to run my app when the user clicks on call log button of the phone?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want my app to run when the user clicks on the call log button.
How can I do that?

Comment: means you want to run another application from current app ?

Comment: You need to use an intent. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556392/how-to-create-an-intent-that-opens-the-call-log-activity

Comment: "click on the call log button" - Which button?

Comment: Are you want to detect user click call button to call ?

Comment: @ paresh Mayani No, In mobile call log history button will be present I want to run my application when that button is clicked.Example:In message locker application when we click on the messages button the lock screen will be shown, which is the message locker app.

Comment: @user370305 The default button in the phone to see the call history   .

Comment: @Herry No, I want to detect when the user click on the call log/call history button.

Comment: As far as I know. Its not possible..

Comment: @user370305 The click on messages button we can detect is right? Then why this is not possible. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please show an example screenshot of what you need

Answer (score 0):

You have to use BroadcastReceiver and app work like service and service activate when you click on call log button and you app work.

This is the concept behind it.

For broadcast receiver http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html